# Dynamic checkbox value not passing

Tags: jquery, laravel

I'm working on dynamic checkboxes. I get the dynamic checkboxes but not able pass their value to the controller.
Here is my script.

```
$(".select_item").click(function(){
         var this_a=$(this.id);
         var txt1=$(".min").html();
         var txt2=$(".max").html();
         var check=new Array(); 
         $("$this_a:checked").each(function() {
           check.push($(this).val());
         });
         alert(check);
         $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "/rng",
             data:{postdata1:txt1,postdata2:txt2,postdata3:check},
            // data: {mydata:"cc"},
            success: function(data) {

                $('#product_image').html(data);
            },
          });
       });
```

when i click the checkbox the script display on message in alertbox.
And here is the view

```
<input type="checkbox" id="p<?php echo $s; ?>" name="cc" class="select_item" data-min="{{$min}}" data-max="{{$max+1}}"/>
<label for="{{'p'.$s}}" id="{{'p'.$s}}">
<span class="button"></span>
Rs.&nbsp;<span class="min"><?php echo $b;?></span>
- Rs. &nbsp;<span class="max"><?php   if($i==4){echo $max+1;}else{echo $b+$a;}?></span>
```

I need to display the range of amount with min and max price

Answer (score 0):

what you correct in script is display blank alert box.
here is script

```
$(".select_item").click(function(){
         var this_a=$('#' + this.id);
         var txt1=$(".min").html();
         var txt2=$(".max").html();
         var check=new Array(); 
         $(':checked', this_a).each(function() {
           check.push($(this).val());
         });
         alert(check);
```

Previous one display on and this script display nothing

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with the code you've posted.

1. `var this_a=$(this.id)` won't select anything, as you're missing the `#` from the start of the selector (you don't need this line anyway, as you can use `this`, which would be the clicked dom element)
2. `$("$this_a:checked")` would be treated literally, and therefore won't select anything. You'd use `$(this).filter(':checked')` instead.
3. The each is redundant, as you're only working with a single checkbox.

You could simplify the code to:

```
$( '.select_item' ).on( 'change', function() {

    var txt1 = $( '.min' ).html(),
        txt2 = $( '.max' ).html(),
        check = [];

    if ( this.checked ) {
        check.push( this.value );
    }

    /* rest of code here */

} );
```